# moveCamera and animateCamera don't work the second time

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the following method for updating my map:

```
private void setCamera() {
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            String[] coords = currentLocation.split(",", 2);
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coords[0]), Double.parseDouble(coords[1])));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);
            mMap.moveCamera(center);
            mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
        }
    }
```

The first time I invoke this method immediately after opening the app, and this method is working fine. But after that I go to another fragment and then to the first fragment again. And in this case the method was invoked, `currentLocation` didn't equal null, `center` got the right `LatLng` object, but my map view didn't change and zoom is less than 5.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I've resolved this issue. I changed the previous code as follows:

```
private void setCamera() {
        if (currentLocation != null) {
            String[] coords = currentLocation.split(",", 2);
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coords[0]), Double.parseDouble(coords[1])));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);
            mapFragment.getMap().moveCamera(center);
            mapFragment.getMap().animateCamera(zoom);
        }
    }
```

And now the map is displayed correctly.