# Google Map AnimateCamera not working the second time

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am struggling with `animateCamera()` method of the Google Maps. It only works on first launch of activity and if the activity is destroyed and created again, camera animations doesn't work but map is loaded fine. I have tried debugging the code, everything gets executed but map doesn't animate without any error or log. Although animation works when same `mapFragment` is used in the fragment but in activity it doesn't seem to work.

The solution mentioned in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853366/movecamera-and-animatecamera-dont-work-the-second-time/) is deprecated now and I am unable to fix this issue.

**Map Fragment**

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
     if (mMap == null) mMap = googleMap;
}
```

**Code for animating camera**

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_LEVEL));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making entire project again from old code fixed the issue. But this issue re-appeared in another app. I found out that application was using old reference to `mMap`. This can be fixed by either getting reference from fragment manager or just setting `mMap = null` when activity is destroyed.